# Extracting searching and performing statistics on 90 million line dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a 90 million line multidimensional list in the form

```
source, target, bayesscore, mean, sd
[['a','1',45.67,-18.34324,15.06]
['a','2',45.32,-18.2234,18.77]
['a','3',44.96,-18.3359,19.24]
['a','4',45.09,-18.13243,21.343]
['a','5',43.82,-18.73456,22.353]
['b','2',43.72,-16.43,11.02] and so on...]
```

I am importing this list from a database and my goal is to pre-calculate values for each of the sources.

foreach source-target pair:

- calculate the z-score = (bayesscore - mean)/sd
- calculate neglogpval np.round(np.log10(1-stats.norm.cdf(x))) if nan nl = '>10', a representative value.
- I then have to filter the top 25 source-target pairs per source by highest bayes score and write it to a file.

I am currently doing this in pandas but it is really really slow.

- I currently work on chunks of 200000 at a time(heuristically picked value)
- store this in a temporary dataframe and then do a groupby(source) on the chunk, add the last group to the next chunk and so on.

Do any of you have suggestions as to how I could make this process any faster?

Comment: Is the file `csv` ? In my experience `pd.read_csv` can be quiet slow.  Maybe this is the cause of the low performances

Comment: dont ... instead job it out to many processes using something like hadoop or spark ... or even just use a redis database + multiprocessing ... trying to do all this in a single process is going to be slow pretty much no matter what  (Im assuming you can accomplish both of those calculations in parts that are later combined)

Comment: Is your data actually starting in a list of lists or was that just an example? Also, assuming your data is in a dataframe, have you tried using .apply() to do your calculations?

Comment: I was using pd.read_csv but I am just changing the code to directly read it into my program from the database.

I'm using the vertica-python module right now and that gives me a multidimensional list, but I could easily manipulate this to a DataFrame.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I agree that does seem to be the best approach. They can be distributed as well. I will look into that

Comment: it does require some paradigm shift in thinking ...

Comment: How much memory do you have in your computer?

Comment: Off-topic tip: Instead of `np.log10(1-stats.norm.cdf(x))`, use `stats.logsf(x) / np.log(10)`.  `sf` stands for `survival function`; it is `1 - cdf(x)`.  `logsf(x)` is the natural log of `sf(x)`.